# How to set a radio button checked dynamically via php?

Tags: php, html

In this code we want to read line 7 of a file with our shell and if the value is "set" we want to change the status of our checkbox to checked.

```
<input type="radio" name="myName" value="myValue"  <?php
     if( shell_exec("./read_from_db 7")=="set") echo ' checked="checked"'
?>
```

It seems this code those not work. Even though line 7 of the file is "set" the radio button is not checked. Why is that? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: can you make sure that `shell_exec("./read_from_db 7")` is giving you exactly `set`?

Comment: yes I am sure about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result coming from `shell_exec` is giving you something extra.

Try using [**trim**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php), so:

```
if( trim(shell_exec("./read_from_db 7"))=="set") echo ' checked="checked"'
```

---

Here is a test:

```
var_dump(shell_exec('echo set'));
echo '<br>';
var_dump(trim(shell_exec('echo set')));
echo '<br>';
$v1 = shell_exec('echo set') == 'set';
$v2 = trim(shell_exec('echo set')) == 'set';
var_dump($v1);
echo '<br>';
var_dump($v2);
```

and the output:

> string(4) "set " 
>   string(3) "set" 
>   bool(false) 
>   bool(true)

You can see that even with no space in the original code, it added something there. My guess is that it is some sort of line break or anything like that.

Comment: @rivas just as a note, that's what I meant when I asked if the result was exactly `set` xD